# Better Search DTO Design

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, design-patterns

How do I make a generic `SearchDTO` which can be used as a template for any Search?

It should have any filter and other general information like TotalRecords, Sort Order, Pages, Start Row, etc

```
public abstract class SearchDTO
{
    public object Id { get; set; }
    public IList<T> SearchResults { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int StartRowNo
    {
        get
        {
            return (CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize;
        }           
    }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
}
```

And any Search Object looks like.

```
public class EmployeeSearchDTO:SearchDTO
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

But I get the following error in `IList<T>` property:

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

How could I specify like returing a `List of any objects` and I can create other property like

```
public long TotalRecords
{
    get
    {
        return SearchResults.Count;
    }
    set;
}
```

Is there any best approach other than this to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify `T` as type parameter on your class:

```
public abstract class SearchDTO<T>
```

Then when you will inherit from it - you should either provide concrete type instead of type parameter:

```
public class EmployeeSearchDTO : SearchDTO<MyConcreteType>
```

or successor class should be generic as well:

```
public class EmployeeSearchDTO<T> : SearchDTO<T>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the declaration on the class as well, to know what type T is:

**Code for abstract class**

```
public abstract class SearchDTO<T>
{
    public object Id { get; set; }
    public abstract IList<T> SearchResults { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int StartRowNo
    {
        get
        {
            return (CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize;
        }           
    }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }    
}
```

`IList<T> SearchResults` must be declare as abstract and override in inherited class.

**Code of EmployeeSearchDTOP**

```
public class EmployeeSearchDTO:SearchDTO<Employee>
{

    public override IList<Employee> SearchResults { get; set; }
}
```

Create `Employee` class and move `FirstName` & `LastName` properties in Employee class.

**Employee Class**

```
 public class Employee
 {
    public string FirstName {get; set; }
    public string LastName {get;set;} 

 }
```

Comment: Did you compile this code? Dont you get the same error `The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`?

Answer (score 0):

Until and unless there is a specific reason for you to use a abstract class what you want can be achieved by simply using a template class:

```
public class SearchDTO<T>
{
    public object Id { get; set; }
    public IList<T> SearchResults { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int StartRowNo
    {
        get
        {
            return (CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize;
        }
    }
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }    
}
```

For creating object all you need to do is this:

```
SearchDTO<EmployeeSearchDTO> obj=new SearchDTO<EmployeeSearchDTO>();
```

And instead of having SearchResults property create a function that would return a list of `EmployeeSearchDTO` objects, like this:

```
public IList<T> SearchResults()
{
    IList<T> listObj=new List<T>();
    //your code here
    return listObj;
}
```

Comment: Why the getter and setters are not working? Internally all getters will be converted to methods. Your approach is not suitable for my case.

Comment: You can use a property as well, it would not matter. But in a situation like this where you need just a getter one should prefer to use function. That way it you decide to send some parameters for for search you could do that. If you want to use abstract class then the two approaches suggested by Sergey and Jignesh are correct.